# Remove an array from another array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create an array from a string and splitting with a comma, and then looking to removing one array from, I have read several posts but cannot get any of these to work, so any help is really appreciated.

```
Dim stringArr As Array = tbOldValues.Text.Split(","c)
Dim FilterData As Array = tkbExistingNames.Text.Split(","c)
```

The above assigns the array, how would I achieve to remove `stringArr` from `FilterData`?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have a fixed size, so there is no working `Remove` method. You have to create a new array. You could use LINQ which simplifies the task with [`Enumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__):

```
FilterData = FilterData.Except(stringArr).ToArray()
```

`Except` returns only those items that are in the first collection but not in the second.

You also have an issue with the type of your array. Don't use `Array` but `String()`. So

```
Dim stringArr As String() = tbOldValues.Text.Split(","c)
Dim FilterData As String() = tkbExistingNames.Text.Split(","c)
```

`System.Array` is the old, non-generic base type of all arrays. You should almost never need it, at least when you know the type(like here `String()`).

Comment: Many thanks Tim, for replying, when I add this code I receive an error: 'Except' is not a member of 'System.Array'.

Comment: @user1824963: you need to add `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes, I did add that to before adding the except code but the error persists - how strange?

Comment: I am using .Net 4.5.2

Comment: I added System.Data.Linq references to my application also.

Comment: Hi, I do not think this is an issue of Linq but they way the array, so I changed this to:             Dim stringArr As String() = {tbOldValues.Text}
    Dim FilterData As String() = {tkbExistingNames.Text}
    Dim resultofcomparison As IEnumerable(Of String) = stringArr.Except(FilterData) But how the array is created.

Comment: @user1824963: no, that looks wrong. You want to split the TextBox.Text so you need to use `String.Split`. That returns a `String()`. Aaah, sorry, now i see the issue. You need to declare it as `String()` not as `Array`. So this is wrong: `Dim stringArr As Array = tbOldValues.Text.Split(","c)` Instead use `Dim stringArr As String() = tbOldValues.Text.Split(","c)` or just use `Dim stringArr = tbOldValues.Text.Split(","c)`

Comment: @user1824963: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Im glad to hear, feel free to accept an answer  to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

I avoid arrays as much as possible, prefer List...  Your problem statement is unclear, **try adding examples**.

With these values

```
    tbOldValues.Text = "two,four,six"
    tkbExistingNames.Text = "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven"
```

I ran this code

```
    Dim stringArr As List(Of String) = tbOldValues.Text.Split(","c).ToList

    Dim FilterData As List(Of String) = tkbExistingNames.Text.Split(","c).ToList

    FilterData = FilterData.Except(stringArr).ToList
```

FilterData had four elements at the conclusion of the code,

```
one
three
five
seven
```